# python variable assignment from file

Tags: python, file

I noticed when I  execute this command:

```
comb = open ("out.txt", "r").readlines()[0]
print comb
```

It will print the first line in the out file and an empty line after it. Why do I have the empty line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [**docs**](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects):

> `readline()` reads a single line from the file; a *newline character (`\n`) **is left at the end of the string***, and is only omitted on the last line of the file if the file doesn’t end in a newline.

You can use this instead:

```
open("out.txt", "r").read().splitlines()[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `readlines()` reads lines with EOL characters, and `print()` adds EOL character after printing provided text. EOL - end of line, usually `\n`.

Answer (score 1):

`file.readlines()` doesn't strip the newline at the end of each line, and `print` adds one.

Answer (score 1):

The empty line is there because the line is read as having a `'\n'` character (newline) at the end of each line. Unfortunately Python doesn't automatically remove this.